# Почему при $(document).ready(function(){}); некорректно работает цикл for?

Tags: jquery

Нужно создать сетку с дивов 16х16. Для этого использую следующий код. Всё работает нормально. Но если прописать $(document).ready(function(){});  - создаётся почему-то в два раза больше строк. В чём может быть проблема?

```
var $container = $("<div></div>").css("float", "left");


    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        $("<div></div>").addClass("box").appendTo($container);
        }
        $("<div></div>").css("clear", "both").appendTo($container);
    }
$container.appendTo($("body"));
```

UPD: вот этот код работает странно

```js
    var $container = $("<div></div>").css("float", "left");

    $(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
   $("<div></div>").addClass("box").appendTo($container);
   }
   $("<div></div>").css("clear", "both").appendTo($container);
  }
    $container.appendTo($("body"));
    });
```

```css
 .box {
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

 </body>
```

Comment: А где вы прописываете `$(document).ready(function(){});`? Приведите пример кода, который выдает ошибку,а не того, который работает

Comment: ' var $container = $("<div></div>").css("float", "left");
  
    $(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
   $("<div></div>").addClass("box").appendTo($container);
   }
   $("<div></div>").css("clear",        "both").appendTo($container);
  }
    $container.appendTo($("body"));
    });'

Comment: Приведенные куски кода работают аналогично. Скорее всего проблема в другом коде. Сделай [сниппет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4619/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B) в котором будет воспроизводиться странное поведение

Comment: нет ли на вашей странице iframe каких-либо?

Comment: @teran нет, ничего такого нет

Comment: @Grundy ничего не пойму, сделал сниппет - здесь всё выполняется как надо. на jsfiddle - тоже норм работает. аналогичный код загруженный с файла в браузере выдаёт хрень

Comment: @ПетрРудык, очевидно _аналогичный код загруженный с файла_ - не такой уж аналогичный. Смотри чем отличается код в файле от кода в сниппете

Comment: Попробуйте переместить объявление переменной $container в обработчик ready

Comment: @Grundy всё, спасибо, нашёл ошибку. Файл со скриптом был два раза подключён, и соответственно дважды выполнялся. LOL.